# Create JSON response from Parsed XML PHP

Tags: php, json, xml

I am parsing thorugh a eBay API response. I want to deliver this back to a website cleaner and easier to parse with JavaScript. I successfuly Parsed through the XML... but now turning that into JSON to resend back to the client is giving me some headaches.

**NOTE**: `$resp` is the response from eBay. It's their full length XML that is successfully parsed with the code below.

**For example**... `$valueName` could be `Grade`. And then I go into the next foreach loop and get the values for this. These `values` may be `10, 9.5, 9` *etc*.

Here is my PHP code.

```
$arrayName = array();
$arrayValue = array();

foreach($resp->aspectHistogramContainer->aspect as $name) {
    $nameAspect = $name['name'];
    //$arrayName["aspectName"] = $nameAspect;

    foreach($name->valueHistogram as $value) {
        $valueAspect = $value['valueName'];
        //$arrayValue["aspectValue"] = $valueAspect;    
    }

    //array_push($arrayName, $arrayValue);
}
echo json_encode($arrayName);
```

So, without me trying to create my own JSON, I am getting that I need. I echos results and it was similar to this...

> NAME
>
> ----- Value
>
> ----- Value
>
> ----- Value
>
> NAME
>
> ----- Value
>
> NAME
>
> etc etc

For a JSON response... Im looking for something like...

```
[
  {
        "name": "NAME",
        "value": ["value", "value"]
    }, {
        "name": "name",
        "value": ["value", "value"]
    }
]
```

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

eBay's response is like this (there are A LOT more `<aspect>` and `<valueHistogram>`)

```
<getHistogramsResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
<ack>Success</ack>
<version>1.13.0</version>
<timestamp>2018-11-07T15:32:20.380Z</timestamp>
<aspectHistogramContainer>
<domainDisplayName>Baseball Cards</domainDisplayName>
<aspect name="Card Manufacturer">
<valueHistogram valueName="Ace Authentic">
<count>19</count>
</valueHistogram>
<valueHistogram valueName="American Caramel">
<count>2024</count>
</valueHistogram>
<valueHistogram valueName="APBA">
<count>10554</count>
</valueHistogram>
<valueHistogram valueName="Bazooka">
<count>8826</count>
</valueHistogram>
<valueHistogram valueName="Be A Player">
<count>17</count>
</valueHistogram>
<valueHistogram valueName="Bell Brand Dodgers">
<count>334</count>
```

Comment: you forgot to show us what `$resp` looks like so we understand how we might need to manipulate it.

Comment: '$resp' is the response from eBay. Its the XML code that is parse. You will be aspectName and aspectValue... that is what i'm working with.

Comment: yes but we need to understand its _structure_ in order to do the translation. I don't want the raw XML, just the PHP object structure. An example of var_dump output would do the job.

Comment: I think you can _probably_ do `$arrayValue["aspectValue"][] = $valueAspect;` but without seeing the actual structure I can't be 100% certain. (You'd probably need `$arrayValue["aspectValue"] = array()` just before that inner loop.

Comment: @ADyson added the structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To encode it (and assuming SimpleXML), then it's just a case of building each internal `$aspect` data array and then adding the values to it.  I use `(string)` to ensure the data is not stored as a SimpleXMLElement, which can cause side effects...

```
$arrayName = array();

foreach($resp->aspectHistogramContainer->aspect as $name) {
    $aspect = [ "name" => (string)$name['name']];

    foreach($name->valueHistogram as $value) {
        $aspect["value"][] = (string)$value['valueName'];
    }
    $arrayName[] = $aspect;
}
echo json_encode($arrayName);
```

with the sample XML, this gives...

```
[{"name":"Card Manufacturer","value":["Ace Authentic","American Caramel","APBA","Bazooka","Be A Player","Bell Brand Dodgers"]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create one single array `$resultArray` and store values in it. By maintaining your current code structure with minimal changes, here is the updated code snippet,

```
$resultArray = array();

$i = 0; // Maintain Array Index value
foreach($resp->aspectHistogramContainer->aspect as $name) {
    $resultArray[$i]["aspectName"] = (string)$name['name'];;

    foreach($name->valueHistogram as $value) {
        $resultArray[$i]["aspectValue"][] = (string)$value['valueName'];
    }
    $i++; // Increment array index to store next value
}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = array();

// Parse the XML into a keyed array

foreach($resp->aspectHistogramContainer->aspect as $name) {
    $nameAspect = (string) $name['name'];
    $values = array();
    foreach($name->valueHistogram as $value) {
        $values[] = (string) $value['valueName'];
    }
    $results[$nameAspect] = $values;
}

// This keeps things simple - rewrite to the required JSON format

$outputForJSON = array();
foreach ($results as $name => $values) {
    $outputForJSON[] = array(
         "name" => $name,
         "values" => $values
    );
}

echo json_encode($outputForJSON);
```

Comment: This gives me an illegal offset type at $results[$nameAspect] = $values;

Comment: Forgot to convert the XML name objects to strings. That should probably fix it!

Comment: why create one structure and then translate it to a second structure? It could all be done in one step (see the other answers)

Comment: Agreed it could all be done in one step, but this example was intended to show how you can rewrite arrays to produce different outputs by using keys. Maybe should have explained that!